# SwiftUI conditionally displayed Button ignores first tap when holding separate LongPressGesture "Shift" Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement something along the lines of a shift key. In the below code, when you hold on the Shift button the A button changes to a B button. However, the B button will not work until you use a second finger to tap anywhere else on the screen.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShifted = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        
        if self.isShifted {
            Button(action: {
                print("B tapped! (shifted!)")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "b.square.fill").imageScale(.large)
            })
        } else {
            Button(action: {
                print("A tapped (non-shifted)")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "a.circle.fill").imageScale(.large)
            })
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: {
            //Means we lifted off the button
            isShifted = false
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "shift.fill").imageScale(.large)
        })
        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0).onEnded({ _ in
            //Means we touched down on the button
            isShifted = true
        }))
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: {
            print("C tapped")
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "c.square").imageScale(.large)
        })
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Some other behavior I have discovered include:

- Touching down on the screen then dragging over the B button triggers it
- The C button remains functional shifted or not

Environment: Xcode 12.5.1 (12E507), running on iPhone 12 with iOS 14.7.1

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem and don't have an iOS 14 device to test on (can't use simulator for this). I tested on iOS 15 built with Xcode 13b5. The A/B button works first time, no matter if it is shifted or not. However: some possible solutions (that I can't test) which _may_ work. 1) Try convert the A/B button to one button, and conditionally change parts of button (e.g. `Image(systemName: isShifted ? "b.square.fill" : "a.circle.fill")`). This means the buttons have the same identity. 2) Try add `.id(isShifted)` to the buttons.

Comment: @George it might be harder for me to implement in my actual code but I'm going to suck it up and go with your option #1. I appreciate your feedback about working on iOS 15, which makes me think this is a rendering bug and not code error.

Comment: Your code works fine on Xcode: 12.5.1 and iPhone 8 iOS 14.6. Weird that you're not getting the expected result.